# The newer Hyperledger-fabric version doesn't contain membersvr module, instead by orderer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've download the newest version from GitHub,and I didn't find the **membersvr module**, but found a new module named **ORDERER**

Did something change?

Answer (score 1):

from https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1001
and https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/2273/

For Fabric v1, the artist known as membership services is now in its own repository (fabric-cop).
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-cop